# Stellar aberration, any prism effect?

Tags: optics

In stellar aberration, is there any prism effect, chromatic aberration?

Comment: I'd like to believe that it looks a little [like this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/85643/51174) but of course it doesn't.

Comment: Since all wavelengths travel at the same speed in vacuum, at most the prism effect would take place in the portion of the path that's in our atmosphere.  I suspect that will be a microscopic fraction -- consider the relative path lengths.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft that's a really good point, why not write up an answer based on that?

Comment: @uhoh  I might -- but then I would feel it necessary to work the calculation :-) . (Yeah I'm feeling lazy this week)